# Filtering data frame in R by calculations based on a column

Tags: r, filter, seq

I have a data frame with multiple columns out of which two of them are dates. 
From one date column, I want to calculate all Sundays from that (date - 14) till todays date. I,then, want to filter my data where the other date column is equal to these dates.
Below is an example : ( original data is much bigger than this one)

```
ex_data <- data.frame(
  c("2018-05-27", "2018-06-24", "2018-07-01", "2018-07-08", "2018-06-25",
    "2018-07-05", "2018-07-10", "2018-05-30", "2018-06-20", "2018-07-04", 
    "2017-12-05"),   
  c("2018-05-13", "2018-02-04", "2018-06-17", "2018-06-10", "2018-04-04", 
    "2018-01-14", "2018-06-17", "2018-06-24", "2018-07-01", "2017-12-03",
    "2018-06-17"), 
  c(rep("1", 4), rep("2", 3), rep("3", 2), rep("1", 1),5),   
  c(rep("xxx", 4), rep("yyyy", 3), rep("zz", 2), rep("xxx", 1),"ttt"))


colnames(ex_data) <- c("Date1", "Date2", "Ex1", "Ex2")
```

I want to find the Sundays two weeks from Date1 to today (lets call it "previousSundays"). The result for each row is a list/vector of sundays from corresponding value of date1 to today. For example, for the first row  it would be:

```
"2018-05-13" "2018-05-20" "2018-05-27" "2018-06-03" "2018-06-10"
"2018-06-17" "2018-06-24" "2018-07-01" "2018-07-08" "2018-07-15" 
"2018-07-22" "2018-07-29"
```

I then want to filter my data frame so that I have only the values where Date2 equals to "previousSundays".

The desired output looks like as below : ( did the calculation one by one only for the first three rows)

```
   Date1           Date2       Ex1  Ex2            
   2018-05-27   2018-05-13       1  xxx
   2018-07-01   2018-06-17       1  xxx
```

Any ideas what would be the best way to do it in R? I used `lapply` and `seq` function but it did not work. Below is what I tried to do:

```
ex_data$prevdays <- lapply(ex_data$Date1 - 14, seq, var2 = Sys.Date(), by = "week")
```

(and some variants of the line above)

I searched already the website/internet but could not find a solution that addresses my problem. Any suggestion is appreciated as I can not find an elegant way to solve this problem.

Comment: what is your desired outcome? can you explain "i want to calculate the dates two weeks from Date1 to today".

Comment: I edited the post.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you can do this by setting up a series of conditionals.

```
# first recode the dates
ex_data[, 1:2] <- lapply(ex_data[, 1:2], as.Date)

# check if date is a sunday    
is.sunday <- format(ex_data$Date2, "%u") == 7

today <- Sys.Date()

# slightly more tricky. Aggregate Date1 over Ex2 and find the minima
mins <- aggregate(Date1 ~ Ex2, data=ex_data, min)

# use the result as a lookup-table
mins <- mins$Date1[match(ex_data$Ex2, mins$Ex2)]

# combine (create the intersect of) the conditions
matches <- ex_data$Date2 > mins - 14 & ex_data$Date2 < today & is.sunday

# and filter the data
ex_data[matches,]

#         Date1      Date2 Ex1  Ex2
# 3  2018-07-01 2018-06-17   1  xxx
# 4  2018-07-08 2018-06-10   1  xxx
# 7  2018-07-10 2018-06-17   2 yyyy
# 8  2018-05-30 2018-06-24   3   zz
# 9  2018-06-20 2018-07-01   3   zz
# 11 2017-12-05 2018-06-17   5  ttt
```

Comment: I did something similar to this but the problem with taking the earliest date minus two weeks is that in my data I have dates going really back( beginning of year, last year) This is becoming problematic when I filter as I do not want all such data for other rows.

Comment: I edited the data with adding extra row with a date from 2017. Your logic will include the row:  "2018-07-04 2017-12-03   1  xxx" , which I do not want.

Comment: @Oezge: What is the earliest date you want to include?

Comment: For each unique value in column Ex2, there is an earliest date.

Comment: @Oezge: And what is that date? How is it decided?

Comment: I don know how to do it, or I am not sure if this is easy to do  but I explain the logic that I want to implement by an example : on column Ex2, we have the values xxxx,yyyy and zzz. Lets take the value xxx. The minimum date in column Date1 corresponding to xxx is "2018-05-07".  Ideally, I would like to calculate the Sundays starting from "2018-05-07"-14 till today. And filter the  data in when Data2 equals to one of these dates. But this is only for xxxx, the same logic should apply to yyyy and zz too. (in my original data, the number of unique entries in Ex2 is much more than 3)

Comment: @Oezge: Hopefully this is closer to what you need.